# Reverse linked list returning new linked list

Tags: c, linked-list

I need to implement a function that reverses a linked list but i don't know how to return a newly formed linked list as a result.

```
typedef struct node_t* Node;

struct node_t {
    int n;
    Node next;
};    

// create a new node with value n
Node nodeCreate(int n) 
{
    Node node = malloc(sizeof(*node));
    if (node == NULL) return NULL;

    node->n = n;
    node->next = NULL;

    return node;
} 

// reversing the linked list
Node reverseList(Node list) 
{
    if (list == NULL) return NULL;

    Node current, prev, next;
    current = rev_head;
    prev = NULL;

    while( current != NULL)
    {
        next = current->next;
        current->next = prev;
        prev = current;
        current = next;
    }

    list = prev;
    return list;
}
```

This is the code I have written so far.

How do I insert this reverse linked list into a different new linked list within the function `reverseList` it self?

Comment: Not directly related, but don't hide pointer definitions with typedefs. It only adds confusion. When if see `Node next;`, nothing tells me that `next` is a actually a pointer

Comment: If you want a _new_ list, simply copy the list and then reverse the _copied_ list.

Comment: I don't understand your question exactly, just return the head of the reversed list

Comment: I want the rev function to return a new list, meaning that i keep the original list and get a new reversed list after the function completes

Comment: You have to make a new link list for that. In the code given you are changing the list that you passed in argument (which you dont want).
make a new link list and reverse it accordingly. There is no easy way for doing this.

Comment: Can it be something like this?                                                                                               
                        Node NewRevList(Node list){
                  
                  Node rev_list;
                 rev_list = listCopy(Node list);
                 reverseList(Node rev_list);
                  return rev_list;
                }          assuming of course that i have implemented the coplylist function

Comment: Yes, of course, It will be a good idea.! Copy the original list, send the copied list to your current function. and return the reversed list.

Answer (score 1):

You are juggling around your nodes on the original list, and modifying then in place - which means you have only one list, and modify its nodes.

If that is what you want, your code might work (as soon as you fix things like the `rev_head` variable that appears from nowhere) - and the new head of the list, which is on your `prev` variable: which means your code should just work.

(It is important that the typedef don't hide the pointer though, I'd suggest changing that.)

What you seem not to have understood quite well is that for this kind o structure, any node works as the head of a list - there is no "list" type, just "node" types - and if you happen to pick any node in the middle of a list, that will just represent a partial list, starting from that node as well. So when you change your previous "last" node to point to its previous "antecessor" as its "next", that is it: that node is now the head.

(The exception to this "node == list" equality is *while* the reversing algorithm is running - at that point you have nodes that point in one direction and nodes that point in another, and the extra "next" and "prev" variables provide the needed information to fix things. If this was production code, this part of the code would have to be protected in a thread-lock)

Otherwise, if you want to produce a reversed copy of the list, you will have to copy the old nodes along the way, and just fix where they are pointing.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct node_t Node;
struct node_t {
    int n;
    Node next;
};    

// create a new node with value n
Node *nodeCreate(int n) {
    Node *node = malloc(sizeof(*node));
    if (node == NULL) return NULL;

    node->n = n;
    node->next = NULL;

    return node;
}   

void nodeCopy(Node *node_dst, Node *node_src) {
    if (node_src == NULL || node_dst == NULL || abs(node_dst - node_src) < sizeof(Node)) {
        return
    }
    memcpy(node_dst, node_src, sizeof(Node));
}

// reversing the linked list
Node *reverseList(Node *list) {
    Node *new_list, *prev;
    if (list == NULL) return NULL;

    new_list = nodeCreate(0);
    nodeCopy(new_list, list);
    new_list->next=NULL;
    prev = new_list;
    while(list->next != NULL) {
        list = list->next;
        new_list = nodeCreate(0);
        nodeCopy(new_list, list);
        new_list->next=prev;
        prev = new_list;   
    }
    return new_list;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply create a new node for every node in the original list and set the link in opposite order. Code could be:

```
Node createReversedList(Node node) {
    Node result = NULL;
    while (node != NULL) {
        Node n = nodeCreate(node->n);
        n->next = result;
        result = n;
        node = node->next;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple way in which you can reverse linked list

You can simply create a new linked list and add each node at the start of linked list which will create same linked list in reverse order

```
Node* revList(Node *start){
Node *startRev=NULL,*temp,*newNode;
temp = start;
while (temp->next!=NULL){
    newNode = (Node *) malloc (sizeof(Node));
    //Code for copying data from temp to new node

    if(startRev == NULL){
        startRev = newNode;
    }
    else {
        newNode->next = startRev;
        startRev = newNode;
    }
    temp = temp->next;
}
return startRev;
}
```